# Office-JS Excel API: problem properly chaining promises

Tags: excel, office-js

I am building an Excel add-in using straight (non-transpiled) JS that executes in an IE11 frame inside of a desktop version of Excel. If that matters, I am also using Vue as a UI framework. I have the following two methods defined (among others, but these two are the shortest, so I will use them to demonstrate my issue):

```
protectSheet: function () {
            return Excel.run(function (context) {
                const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

                return context.sync().then(function () {
                    sheet.protection.protect({
                        userInterfaceOnly: true,
                        drawingObjects: false
                    }); // allow inserting comments

                    return context.sync();
                });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error: " + error);
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
            });
        }
```

and

```
unProtectSheet: function () {
                return Excel.run(function (context) {
                    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
                    sheet.load("protection/protected");

                    return context.sync().then(function () {
                        if (sheet.protection.protected) {
                            sheet.protection.unprotect();
                        }

                        return context.sync();
                    });
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("error: " + error);
                    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                    }
                });
            }
```

I am then calling them is the following way, hoping that it will mean that the second funciton begins executing only after the first one is fully finished:

```
onChange: function () {
        this.unProtectSheet()
            .then(this.protectSheet());
    }
```

However, the second function gets kicked off immediately after the first one, without waiting for the first one to complete. I am clearly missing a point on how Office-JS promises work (or promises in general). What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.

However, if you use the `.then(funcName)` syntax, you have to only give the function pointer, NOT invoke it.  That is, instead of `.then(this.protectSheet())`, drop the `()` and keep it as `.then(this.protectSheet)`.

```
onChange: function () {
    this.unProtectSheet()
        .then(this.protectSheet);
}
```

Alternatively, do:

```
onChange: function () {
    this.unProtectSheet()
        .then(function() {
            return this.protectSheet();
        });
}
```

And BTW, you should really have a ".catch" at the end as well, to catch any errors that happen in either function.

... And of course, this would look rather cleaner with async/await (e.g., transpiling via TypeScript or Babel or whatever).

Comment: OMG, this seems so obvious now that you pointed this out! Thank you so much -- this was a clear case of staring at my code for too long. Follow-up question -- in you first code snippet, did you mean to omit the () after the protectSheet pointer)?

I will make sure this solution works when I get back to the office (although I am sure it will) and will accept your answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was a copy-paste error.  Updated now.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Also, for the benefit of the folks referring to the code for use in their projects: in the "Alternative" example above, the "this" in line 4 will probably be undefined and will need to be passed in or bound to the inner function explicitly.